# How to make UITableViewCell resizable with EasyPeasy?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I know there was a lot of questions about it. But, I have problem with this anyway. I have `UIImageView` that needs to have specific size and `UILabel` that needs to have dynamic height. I want to show label on the right side of image. I try not to use storyboard, so here is how I gave constraints using `EasyPeasy` library:

```
myImage.easy.layout([Top(8), Left(20), Width(95), Height(95), Bottom()])
    myLabel.easy.layout(Top().to(myPicture, .top), Left().to(myPicture, .right), Right(), Bottom())
```

Below is the result: 
[image]

As you see, when the text is big, it doesn't fit in cell. I set `numberOfLines` as zero for label. As I've understood, my image defines the size of the cell and the label can only cover the area that it actually can have. So, what can be the problem? How to solve it? How to make label's height resizable, despite image height? Is order of constraints important?

Comment: Did you use Table View Automatic Row Dimension?

Comment: Yes, here is how I did it: `myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400

        myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: Can you share constraints of the imageView, because it seems that tableView cell is getting the height based on imageView.

Comment: Of course, here it is: `myImage.easy.layout([Top(8), Left(20), Width(95), Height(95), Bottom()])`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how EasyPeasy works but I think you should use something like this:

```
myImage.easy.layout([Top(8), Left(20), Width(95), Height(95), Bottom(>=0)])
myLabel.easy.layout([Top(20), Left().to(myPicture, .right), Right(), Bottom(20), Height(>=90)])
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help. I also had this idea, but is it ok when you set to `myLabel` left constraint to `myPicture`, event if `myPicture` has no constraints yet?

Comment: I edited my answer can you try it again, and why do you use myImage and then myPicture variable? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Sorry, they are the same. You updated answer is more close to solution. Now, label is totally showing, but `myImage` is at the bottom of the cell. I would it on top:) But, how you come up to solution? What `>=` means?

Comment: It means constraint is equal or bigger than 8, ok I will change solution again. Now the image should stay on top of the view.

Comment: No, unfortunately. Images not shown fully, they stay on top of images on below cell or something like that. Layout has ruined. I don't know why(

Comment: can you add height to myImage like this: `Height(>= 90)`

Comment: Didn't work. Can you give explanation why we need to give bottom constraint when we give him height constraint?

Comment: Ok try without bottom constraint and I think it should be ok

Comment: No. Some cells show image, some not. When scrolling some images disappear even.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182988/discussion-between-dionizb-and-abay).